# Why do I always get a "trailing characters" error when trying to parse data with serde_json?

Tags: json, rust

I have a server that returns requests in a JSON format. When trying to parse the data I always get "trailing characters" error. This happens only when getting the JSON from postman

```rust
let type_of_request = parsed_request[1];
let content_of_msg: Vec<&str> = msg_from_client.split("\r\n\r\n").collect();

println!("{}", content_of_msg[1]); 
// Will print "{"username":"user","password":"password","email":"dwadwad"}"

let res: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(content_of_msg[1]).unwrap();

println!("The username is: {}", res["username"]);
```

when getting the data from postman this happens:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("trailing characters", line: 1, column: 60)', src\libcore\result.rs:997:5
```

but when having the string inside Rust:

```rust
let j = "{\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"password\",\"email\":\"dwadwad\"}";

let res: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(j).unwrap();

println!("The username is: {}", res["username"]);
```

it works like a charm:

```
The username is: "user"
```

**EDIT**: Apparently as I read the message into a buffer and turned it into a string it saved all the NULL characters the buffer had which are of course the trailing characters.

Comment: What does the data look like around line 1 column 63 like the error refers to? The json object you showed is not 63 columns long so that is not what is being deserialized.

Comment: @dtolnay My mistake, I realized now I took a different error from testing different values.
It says line 1 column 60 when sending the data I present in the question.

Comment: It's great that you have the solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the serde json [code](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/6ac689b2b327ed00e8a56d812a5c860177ab10dd/src/error.rs#L247), one finds the following comment above the relevant ErrorCode enum element:

```
/// JSON has non-whitespace trailing characters after the value.
TrailingCharacters,
```

So as the error code implies, you've got some trailing character which is not whitespace. In your snippet, you say:

```
println!("{}", content_of_msg[1]); 
// Will print "{"username":"user","password":"password","email":"dwadwad"}"
```

If you literally copy and pasted the printed output here, I'd note that I wouldn't expect the output to be wrapped in the leading and trailing quotation marks. Did you include these yourself or were they part of what was printed? If they were printed, I suspect that's the source of your problem.

Edit:

In fact, I can nearly recreate this using a raw string  with leading/trailing quotation marks in Rust:

```
extern crate serde_json;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_serde() {
        let s =
            r#""{"username":"user","password":"password","email":"dwadwad"}""#;
        println!("{}", s);
        let _res: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(s).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Running it via `cargo test` yields:

```
test tests::test_serde ... FAILED

failures:

---- tests::test_serde stdout ----
"{"username":"user","password":"password","email":"dwadwad"}"
thread 'tests::test_serde' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("trailing characters", line: 1, column: 4)', src/libcore/result.rs:997:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.


failures:
    tests::test_serde
```

Note that my printed output also includes leading/trailing quotation marks and I also get a `TrailingCharacter` error, albeit at a different column.

Edit 2:

Based on your comment that you've added the wrapping quotations yourself, you've got a known good string (the one you've defined in Rust), and one which you believe should match it but doesn't (the one from Postman).

This is a data problem and so we should examine the data. You can adapt the below code to check the good string against the other:

```
#[test]
fn test_str_comp() {
    // known good string we'll compare against                                                                                                                                             
    let good =
        r#"{"username":"user","password":"password","email":"dwadwad"}"#;
    // lengthened string, additional characters                                                                                                                                            
    // also n and a in username are transposed                                                                                                                                             
    let bad =
        r#"{"useranme":"user","password":"password","email":"dwadwad"}abc"#;
    let good_size = good.chars().count();
    let bad_size = bad.chars().count();
    for (idx, (c1, c2)) in (0..)
        .zip(good.chars().zip(bad.chars()))
        .filter(|(_, (c1, c2))| c1 != c2)
    {
        println!(
            "Strings differ at index {}: (good: `{}`, bad: `{}`)",
            idx, c1, c2
        );
    }
    if good_size < bad_size {
        let trailing = bad.chars().skip(good_size);
        println!(
            "bad string contains extra characters: `{}`",
            trailing.collect::<String>()
        );
    } else if good_size > bad_size {
        let trailing = good.chars().skip(bad_size);
        println!(
            "good string contains extra characters: `{}`",
            trailing.collect::<String>()
        );
    }

    assert!(false);
}
```

For my example, this yields the failure:

```
test tests::test_str_comp ... FAILED

failures:

---- tests::test_str_comp stdout ----
Strings differ at index 6: (good: `n`, bad: `a`)
Strings differ at index 7: (good: `a`, bad: `n`)
bad string contains extra characters: `abc`
thread 'tests::test_str_comp' panicked at 'assertion failed: false', src/lib.rs:52:9
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.


failures:
    tests::test_str_comp
```

Comment: The quotation marks are just to show what will be printed. The raw print is:
`{"username":"user","password":"password","email":"dwadwad"}`

Comment: @Tomdrc1 I've updated my answer. Can't tell you exactly what's different about the data you're receiving from Postman, but I've added a test you can adapt to check it for yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me realize I have alot of NULL after the actual data because I read the data from the socket into a buffer. The "trailing charters" are just null. I realized this when the length of the message was 239 long.